How to fix missing javaaccessbridge.dll dependency, when starting a javafx application?
We are facing an error at a client, who runs our application on (almost equal configured) terminal servers. On several instances our application works as expected, on the rest in throws the following error:
[1]:[Wed, 13 Mar 2024 06:58:41 +0100]:[INFO]:[T1]:[com.app.error.d#<init>]: Uncaught Exception Handler für Thread main initialized.
[2]:[Wed, 13 Mar 2024 06:58:41 +0100]:[WARNING]:[T14]:[com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl#startup]: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from unnamed module @16472056
[3]:[Wed, 13 Mar 2024 06:58:44 +0100]:[INFO]:[T18]:[com.app.error.d#<init>]: Uncaught Exception Handler für Thread JavaFX Application Thread initialized.
[4]:[Wed, 13 Mar 2024 06:58:45 +0100]:[SEVERE]:[T1]:[com.app.main.c#b]: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Ausführen der Applikation aufgetreten: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: O:\MyApplication\runtime\bin\javaaccessbridge.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.accessibility/com.sun.java.accessibility.internal.AccessBridge$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.accessibility/com.sun.java.accessibility.internal.AccessBridge$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.accessibility/com.sun.java.accessibility.internal.AccessBridge.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.accessibility/com.sun.java.accessibility.internal.ProviderImpl.activate(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.lambda$loadAssistiveTechnologies$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.error.SorryDialog.<init>(SorryDialog.java:146)
    at com.app.error.d.<init>(LptUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:77)
    at com.app.main.c.start(LptApplication.java:194)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more

The application is a JavaFX Application, where you can draw items on a canvas. It is deployed with the latest JDK 11, and the embedded runtime is bundled in a folder named runtime. Since each machine has the same version of our application I was wodering if anyone might has a clue, what could cause this error?
The relevant code in the SorryDialog class is the following:
 public SorryDialog( final Stage owner )
  {
    root = (Parent) LptFXMLLoader.loadFXML( this, "SorryDialog.fxml" );

    this.owner = owner;

    if ( Desktop.isDesktopSupported() )
    {
      desktop = Optional.ofNullable( Desktop.getDesktop() );
    }
    else
    {
      desktop = Optional.empty();
    }

   ...
   }

After some research I found some information, that the javaaccessbridge.dll is responsible for assistive technologies. So I thought installing the latest c++ runtime might fix this issue, but this didn't do the trick.
Has anyone else a clue, on what could cause this error?
Update: The error occurs when calling the line if ( Desktop.isDesktopSupported() )
We use the call to awt.Desktop here to check, if a desktop environment is even present, and if so, to get information like, if Mail or Print is an option, to give the user possible ways to proceed, when an unexpected error occured. Is there a JavaFX equivalent of awt.Desktop?
Another hurdle for me is, I never succeded in reproducing this error. The app runs on more then 100 customers successfully. Its just one customer, who has instances where the application works, and others where the error occurs.

I’m curious what an “embedded runtime” is, exactly.  An exact copy of the entire JDK?  A jlink’d application?  A “fat jar”?  What command (or generated script or binary) is used to run the application?

@jewelsea, glad to see you are still here. I remember you were already around when we started our app many years ago. So thank you for that! :-)
Your "little" awt hint changed my whole perspective on that error. I just assumed, our SorryDialog was within the stacktrace, because it is responsible to catch uncaught exceptions and give the user options to proceed. But I´d never expect him to be
the cause of the issue, while beeing initialized! This brings me one step further, but honestly I am still not sure on how to proceed. I updated the question, added details and also the relevant code.

@VGR we still use the Java8 JavaFX Packager to build and deploy the application. There you have options to deploy the application with a specific runtime: fx:bundleArgument / fx:platform, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javafxpackager.html. So we deliever the application with a specific JRE, to be independed from already installed JREs on the target system. Unfortunatly its development was stopped and it didn´t make it in Java 11 anymore. A replacement for the JavaFX Packager was introduced in Java17, when I am not wrong.

@jewelsea concerning your mentioned migration to 21 LTS, this is already considered, but unfortunatly this will have a signifikant impact on our deploy chain, since we want to migrate to the new FX Packager and so far we just didn`t have the time to face this situation. But this is one step on the roadmap in the second half this year.
Hope I now fulfil the requirements to not close this ticket and I appreciate your help in this case.

All AWT methods need to be called from the AWT event dispatch thread.  desktop should be volatile and that entire if/else should be inside a Runnable passed to EventQueue.invokeAndWait or EventQueue.invokeLater.  I don’t know whether that alone is the cause of your issue, but it may be a factor.

@VGR That is an interesting point, thank you. I guess I can just refactor the code to gather these states before I initialize the JavaFX Thread. I am just wondering if this is the reason for the error. Why it reproducible occures in such rare cases? On most systems it runs without any exceptions. Nevertheless, I will give it a try. Unfortunatly so far I can only test it on the customer end, so I´d prefer to be sure, I found the mistake.

Threading issues tend to be intermittent, since thread scheduling and unsynchronized data sharing are difficult to predict.

To add additional info, it is often best to edit the question (either changing existing text or adding new text as long it stays on target for the question subject), rather than posting comments.

You have numerous issues and potential issues.  I have listed some of them here, but there may be others.
This is being triggered by Swing API calls made by your class: com.app.error.SorryDialog.
Issue: You are using swing or awt functions and that is triggering (failed) attempts to load assistive technologies used by Swing
JavaFX has its own assistive technology framework which (as far as I know) is not dependent on Swing or the javaaccessbridge.dll at all, making a dependency on Swing and javaaccessbridge.dll unnecessary.
The code is using some Swing or Awt functions which should not be necessary in a JavaFX application.
There is no direct equivalent of the awt Desktop class in JavaFX, but similar functionality for some of its features is provided through different JavaFX services. The closest things are HostServices, Platform, ConditionalFeature, the print API, and undocumented settings and code in the JavaFX implementation.
If those other options suffice you can consider them instead, or you may want to consider eliminating the feature requiring Desktop. From your code, your use of Desktop seems optional anyway.
Issue: You are generating an unhandled exception before you try to load the javaaccessbridge.dll
The SorryDialog is shown because you have an uncaught exception handler LptUncaughtExceptionHandler catching an exception and creating the dialog.
This indicates that you have an exception of some kind occurring before you even get to the point where you try to display the dialog and load assistive tech.
You should probably address whatever is causing that uncaught exception and handle the situation appropriately.
Issue: The frameworks you are using are outdated
JavaFX 11/JDK 11 are quite old, I would recommend the recent versions of 21 LTS for each.  Especially since you seem to be bundling a runtime and have control over that.
Issue: You are using JavaFX in an unsupported mode
The log warns that JavaFX is being deployed in an unsupported mode, indicating JavaFX classes are on the classpath rather than the module path.
Issue: Your threading logic has bugs
As mentioned by VGR in comments:

All AWT methods need to be called from the AWT event dispatch thread.  desktop should be volatile and that entire if/else should be inside a Runnable passed to EventQueue.invokeAndWait or EventQueue.invokeLater. I don’t know whether that alone is the cause of your issue, but it may be a factor.
Threading issues tend to be intermittent, since thread scheduling and unsynchronized data sharing are difficult to predict.

Threading errors can often cause Race Conditions:

A race condition can be difficult to reproduce and debug because the end result is nondeterministic and depends on the relative timing between interfering threads. Problems of this nature can therefore disappear when running in debug mode, adding extra logging, or attaching a debugger. A bug that disappears like this during debugging attempts is often referred to as a "Heisenbug". It is therefore better to avoid race conditions by careful software design.

Issue: Assistive technology availability may vary by platform and machine
The presence or operation of the assistive technology might vary from system to system. There might be specific code you need to provide to handle the lack of such technology on certain systems.  But I don't know the root cause of your issue.
Issue: Your packaging mechanism mixes versions
You have a strange setup in that you are using a JavaFX 8 packager with Java 11 runtime.
That combo may not package the assistive technologies as you wish.
O:\MyApplication\runtime\bin\javaaccessbridge.dll: Can't find dependent libraries 

means the required DLL probably doesn't even exist on some of your target machines or, if it does, something prevented it from loading correctly.
Java 11 makes Java modular, placing DLLs in JDK images, linked from jmods or other modules, so the DLLs may not even be on the file path or accessible to the Java 8 packager so it can appropriately package them.
